# Create trigger using variable from table

Tags: mysql

I'm relatively new to triggers in MYSQL, so sorry if this is a pretty basic thing I'm trying to do. I've found how to set one up allowing a static update, however I haven't seen anything about how to use one of the fields from the inital update as a variable inside the trigger statement

Example:

Table 1, `items`:

```
id | name | total_stock
1 | item | 8
2 | item2 | 0
```

Table 2, `item_options`:

```
id | item_id | option | stock
1 | 1 | test | 5
2 | 1 | test2 | 3
3 | 2 | test | 0
```

If I then update `item_options`:

```
UPDATE `item_options` SET `stock`=7 WHERE `id`=1
```

Or insert a new item into `item_options`:

```
INSERT INTO `item_options` (`item_id`,`option`,`stock`) VALUES ('2','add','2')
```

Then I'd like (if it's possible) to use a trigger to update the `total_stock` in the `items` table with the SUM of `stock` in the `item_options` table with the same corresponding `item_id`.

So, I guess my question is in two parts:

1. Is this possible?
2. Can someone point me in the right direction of how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the pseudo rows `new` or `old` as [described here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html).

It should be something along these lines:

```
CREATE
TRIGGER my_trigger after insert, update
ON item_options FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    update items set total_stock = (select sum(stock) from item_options where item_id = new.item_id) where item_id = new.item_id;
END;
```

Please note that I haven't tested it, but it should give you the general idea.